# How can I make datetime.now() returns a timezone aware date object?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I'm changing an application to save all the dates in UTC. The application uses `datetime.now()` in many places across several modules. I would like a way in which `datetime.now()` be in UTC timezone by default without having to change every line to `timezone.now()` or `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` nor something similar.

The application is in python 3.6.6. 
I thought that changing `USE_TZ` to `True` and set `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'` when calling `datetime.now()` would return a timezone aware date object, but it's not working. Is there a way to accomplish this without changing line by line?

Comment: `datetime.now()` returns local time by default (operating system setting), not UTC (see [src](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bac170cd93bbae939fcb29ccc6b5d423f7f4a089/Lib/datetime.py#L858)). A simple find & replace might leave you with unexpected results.

Comment: Furthermore, are you sure that you can make *some* datetime objects in your code tz-aware without consequences? I mean, if there are other, naive dt objects around, dt arithmetic might fail.